# brew install zlib throws an error on osx mavericks

Tags: php, macos, osx-mavericks, homebrew, zlib

I first attempted to install josegonzalez/homebrew-php. It failed at the zlib install. I then tried to just install zlib, and it failed in the very same manner. Below is the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Indatuss-MacBook-Pro-7% brew install zlib
==> Downloading http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file configure
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8
==> make install
make: *** [inflate.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make: *** [trees.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make: *** [deflate.o] Error 1
```

Not sure what is causing this error, or much less how to fix it.

Answer (score 10):

Try this

> brew tap homebrew/dupes
>
> brew install zlib
>
> brew list zlib

Comment: Error: undefined method `desc' for Formulary::Formulae::Zlib:Class

Comment: Worked like a boss on El Capitan after I got `brew install zlib` 'not found'. Thanks!